# Can I use the same qiskit account on two laptops?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience

I have two laptops with different accounts of Jupyter Notebook. I'm wondering can I use the same qiskit account (with the same token) on both laptops? I'm worried that if I run the token on my new laptop, the original one will be terminated. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can use the same token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that without a problem. They only control the total number of experiments or jobs that you have submitted simultaneously. As long as the total number of submitted jobs (currently 5) are met with your account, regardless of the specifications from where they are submitted, it is ok.

Good luck!